# Custom HDRIs in Material preview

Tags: hdri

Is there a way of using custom hdris in material preview mode, whether it be by going into the program files or is there a way of doing it inside blender?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily install custom HDRIs by using the file selector found in the settings under Lights > HDRIs.

[image: Lighting settings]

The dimensions of the default ones are 1024x512, but aside from a longer loading time higher resolutions work as well.